# Alert Box - should hide when only click on (x)

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert, box

I have simple code for alert box. After only click (x)  should hide element.

**iusse:** The problem is that I can click anywhere on the website, then the element automatically hides. I would like the element to be hidden when only clicking on (x).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   let dismissed = sessionStorage.getItem("dismissed");
   let alertDiv = document.getElementById("promo");
   let dismissButton = document.getElementById("dismiss");
   if(!dismissed){
     alertDiv.classList.remove("hide");
   }

  addEventListener("click", function(){
    alertDiv.classList.add("hide");
    sessionStorage.setItem("dismissed", true);
  });
});
```

```css
/* The alert PROMO box */
.promo {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #415ca2; /* Blue */
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.hide {
display: none;
}

/* The close button */
.closebtnpr {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the close button */
.closebtnpr:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo hide" id="promo"> 
  <span class="closebtnpr" id="dismiss">x</span>
  <center>
    <b>U.S. POLO ASSN. DAY!</b><br />
  </center>
</div>
```

update:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   let dismissed = sessionStorage.getItem("dismissed");
   let alertDiv = document.getElementById("promo");
   let dismissButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alertDiv.classList.add("hide");
    sessionStorage.setItem("dismissed", true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `dismissButton.addEventListener('click', ...`

Comment: Now the alert box is not displayed after making this change.

Comment: What @n8jadams wrote is the exact right solution. You probably have dismissed  set to true in your sessionStorage.

Comment: @GaloisGirl Can you please check my code after correct from update?

Comment: The variable dismissButton is not set, you had it right the first time:
    `let dismissButton = document.getElementById("dismiss")`

Answer (score 2):

```
let dismissed = sessionStorage.getItem("dismissed");
let dismissButton = document.getElementById("dismiss");
let alertDiv = document.getElementById("promo");

if(!dismissed){
    alertDiv.classList.remove("hide");
}

dismissButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alertDiv.classList.add("hide");
    sessionStorage.setItem("dismissed", true);
});
```

You are storing a session variable, so your box will not show up after the box has been clicked until that session variable is deleted.

Comment: I change script on your code but now element still every time are hiden. I also try on private browser.

Comment: That is what the code is set to do. Do you want it to show every time? If so, remove the lines that include sessionStorage and the 'hide' class from the element with Id='promo'

Comment: Otherwise, open a new window on incognito mode every time you want to test it. Refreshing the window will keep the element hidden because session variables are deleted from private windows when they are closed. So make sure you close all your windows in incognito mode.

Comment: what I want to do. When customer open website then: display alert. When customer click on (x) button then hide alert. When customer browse website then no display again alert. But when customer close website, and again open website then again display alert. Now when I put your code then element no display it is not displayed at all. Even when I close the browser completely and open it again also  in the private window - then the element does not show up at all.

Comment: Our script version display correct, but only issue when you click anywhere on the page, the element is hidden. It should work hiding only after pressing the (x) button. You can check it here: https://gerris.pl/